# Registering aliases types of custom MetaType in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, typedef, qt-signals, qmetatype

I have a simple custom type `XyztReal` and its aliases in my `datamodel.h` header file:

```
#ifndef IMUCONTROLLERDATAMODEL_H
#define IMUCONTROLLERDATAMODEL_H

#include <QMetaType>

namespace imu_controller {
namespace data {

// some code

struct __attribute__((__packed__)) XyztReal {
    qreal x ;
    qreal y ;
    qreal z ;
    qreal ts;
};

typedef XyztReal GyrReal;
typedef XyztReal AccReal;
typedef XyztReal MagReal;

void registerTypes();

}
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(imu_controller::data::XyztReal)

#endif // IMUCONTROLLERDATAMODEL_H
```

and registering function in source `datamodel.cpp`:

```
void registerTypes()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<XyztReal>("XyztReal");   // or qRegisterMetaType<XyztReal>();
    qRegisterMetaType<GyrReal >("GyrReal" );
    qRegisterMetaType<AccReal >("AccReal" );
    qRegisterMetaType<MagReal >("MagReal" );
}
```

So i call this function in proper place in programm and try to connect *signals/slots* of some objects in different thread like this:

```
Qt::ConnectionType ct = static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection);
connect(data_ctrl, &imu_controller::DataController::gyrRealReady, this, &MainWindow::someSlot, ct);
```

where *signal/slot* has `imu_controller::data::GyrReal` and `imu_controller::data::XyztReal` arguments type respectively, or:

```
Qt::ConnectionType ct = static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection);
connect(data_ctrl, &imu_controller::DataController::gyrRealReady, this, &MainWindow::onImuGyrRealReceived, ct);
```

where *signal/slot* has `imu_controller::data::GyrReal` arguments type both, But program does not works and debuger prints:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'imu_controller::data::GyrReal'
>   (Make sure 'imu_controller::data::GyrReal' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

for all `XyztReal` aliases types.

**Important:**
The program works if `imu_controller::DataController` class signals type changed to `XyztReal` types!

**PS:**
I think the problem at types registering.
I read qt docs and several topics but i don't found a solution or any examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, the `const char * typeName` argument of `qRegisterMetaType` is quite necessary here. Also it takes consistency in terms of namespaces.

Say you have this signal in your `DataController` class:

```
signals:
    void some_signal(data::AccReal);
```

Since the class lies in the `imu_controller` namespace, you just add the `data` namespace before the argument class name.

Now, in your `registerTypes` function, it should be registered like this:

```
qRegisterMetaType<AccReal >("data::AccReal");
```

In other words, the `typeName` string must match exactly the type of the signal argument **as it is written there**.

It looks like one can register a type more than once, specifying different typenames, i.e.

```
qRegisterMetaType<AccReal >("AccReal");
qRegisterMetaType<AccReal >("data::AccReal");
qRegisterMetaType<AccReal >("imu_controller::data::AccReal");
```

Curiously, if you have a

```
using WhatEver = imu_controller::data::AccReal;
```

somewhere, then you can have

```
signals:
    void some_signal(WhatEver);
```

as long as you have

```
 qRegisterMetaType<AccReal >("WhatEver");
```

To summarize things up, your register function could be like:

```
QString aliases[] = {"XyztReal", "GyrReal", "AccReal", "MagReal" };
for(auto a : aliases)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<XyztReal>(a.toLatin1());

    a.prepend("data::");
    qRegisterMetaType<XyztReal>(a.toLatin1());

    a.prepend("imu_controller::");
    qRegisterMetaType<XyztReal>(a.toLatin1());
}
```

i.e. you can register `XyztReal` several times, one for each possible alias with every possible combination of namespaces.

Comment: Yea, thank you.
To be clear, `const char * typeName` should always consists full `namespace` path?
I have *signal* as `imu_controller::data::AccReal`